# Number of ordered permutations in $ad-bc = 1$, where $(a,b,c,d)$ are integers in $\mathbb Z_{5}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I tried to reduce it down to all the combinations where gcd(a,b) = 1, but I see that it wont do much, and now I really don't know how to proceed. I managed to solve a similar task for $\mathbb Z_{3}$, but with bruteforce, so now I was wondering if you have a hint or something. It would help a lot.

Comment: Do you mean the number of ordered quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ over $\Bbb Z_5$ such that $ad-bc\equiv1\pmod5$?

Comment: The task does not say so, but Im going to show that the number is equal to 120. The number would probably been much smaller if it wasnt the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean all the possible quadruples $\;a,b,c,d\;$ s.t. $\;ad-bc=1\;$ , this is just the order of the special linear group $\;SL_2(\Bbb F_5)\;$:

$$\left|SL_2(\Bbb F_5)\right|=\frac{\left|GL_2(\Bbb F_5)\right|}{\left|\Bbb F_5^*\right|}=\frac{(5^2-1)(5^2-5)}{4}=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean $ad-bc\equiv1\pmod5\ldots$

**Hint**.  See if you can find the number of possibilities at each stage.

Case 1: $a\equiv0$ (one possibility).  Then $d$ is arbitrary (how many possibilities?) and $bc\equiv-1$ (how many possibilities?).

Case 2: $a\not\equiv0$.  Then $b,c$ are arbitrary and the congruence $ad\equiv1+bc$ gives a unique solution for $d$.

Total. . . ?